# How to use maps as location input in react?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-search

I am trying to make a form that a user can search their location or pin his location. I am using `react-leaflet` for loading a map and `react-leaflet-search` for adding the search functionality. 
The search functionality is working fine. Below you can see the code.

```
<Map center={position} zoom={zoom}  onDragEnd = {function(e){ console.log(e);}} >
  <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'/>
  <Search 
    position="topright" 
    showPopup={false} 
    provider="OpenStreetMap" 
    showMarker={true} 
    openSearchOnLoad={true} 
    closeResultsOnClick={true} 
    providerOptions={{ region: "np" }}/>
</Map>
```

What I want to do is to access user's entered location or latitude longitude of the marker that is displayed after user selects the location. I tried to search for event listeners, but could not find any. Currently I am trying to use `onDragEnd` event but I have not succeeded yet. Could anyone tell me how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [react-leaflet-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-search) has not a proper way to retrieve search results. There is `mapStateModifier` callback that we can use to get the search result coordinates `LatLng` object, but we'll have to setup the map `flyTo` call as well:

```jsx
render() {
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];
  const zoom = 13;

  return (
    <div>
      <Map 
        ref={ref => this.mapRef = ref}
        center={position} 
        zoom={zoom}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' />

        <ReactLeafletSearch 
          ref={ref => this.mapSearchRef = ref}
          mapStateModifier={(latLng) => {

            // Do work with result latitude, longitude
            console.log('Search Latitude:', latLng.lat);
            console.log('Search Longitude:', latLng.lng);

            if (this.mapRef) {
              // Because we have a custom mapStateModifier callback,
              // search component won't flyTo coordinates
              // so we need to do it using our refs
              this.mapRef.contextValue.map.flyTo(
                latLng,
                this.mapSearchRef.props.zoom,
                this.mapSearchRef.props.zoomPanOptions
              );
            }
          }}
          position="topright" 
          showPopup={false} 
          provider="OpenStreetMap" 
          showMarker={true} 
          openSearchOnLoad={true} 
          closeResultsOnClick={true} 
          providerOptions={{ region: "np" }}
        />
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check this example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-search-callback) to see it working.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did a wrap around to solve the problem. But I will check if this is a proper way.

Comment: Hi there I am trying to understand the solution and apply it. Could you explain some more? And also do you know any way of making the search marker draggable.

Comment: Why you can't apply it? Did you open the Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-search-callback)? It has this whole code working.

Comment: Yeah I can apply it. But I am asking if there is a way to make the marker that appears after the search draggable?

Comment: You can apply a drag functionality to `leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane` but that only make the marker to move, you won't get any latitude and longitude. That's hard to implement. You can search in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues for this but I don't think it's implemented.